# How to Disable width for carousel control buttons bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I have a problem with carousel control buttons bootstrap as show in this photo :[image]

But as soon as i disable `width: 15%` in the the `devTools` in chrome i don't have that problem any more : [image] [image]

I tried to set `width: auto` but couldn’t figure out how to fix that in my code below, is there any way to disable the `width` of the `carousel-control-prev` and `carousel-control-next` :

```css
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  .carousel-inner {
    .carousel-item {
      .testimony {
        display: flex;
        img {
          width: 150px;
          height: 150px;
          object-fit: cover;
          aspect-ratio: 1;
          border-radius: 75px;
          margin-right: 27px;
        }
        .name {
          font-weight: bold;
          display: block;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .carousel-control-prev,
  .carousel-control-next {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .carousel-control-prev-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    mask-image: url("../../public/img/carousel-arrow.svg");
    background-color: $red;
    transition: background-color 100ms ease-in, opacity 100ms ease-in;
    &:hover {
      background-color: #DF011F;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
  }
  .carousel-control-next-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    mask-image: url("../../public/img/carousel-arrow.svg");
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    background-color: $red;
    transition: background-color 100ms ease-in, opacity 100ms ease-in;
    &:hover {
      background-color: #DF011F;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
    .carousel-control-prev-icon {
      transform: scale(0.75);
    }
    .carousel-control-next-icon {
      transform: rotate(180deg) scale(0.75);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="testimony">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/talents/sylvie.jpg') }}" alt="john doe" class="d-none d-lg-block">
        <div>
          <p>test</p>
          <span class="name">John Doe</span>
          <span class="job">Chief</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To override bootstrap default styles simply add a `!important` to the end of you CSS style.

In this case that would be:

```css
.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing :

> .carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next { width: auto !important; }